# How to avoid opening external programs in tclsh

Tags: tcl, tclsh

Typing 'as' in my development environment causes tclsh to be unresponsive

```
mytcl % as


^C
child killed: interrupt
while evaluating as
mytcl %
```

I don't care what kind of program is opened by the as command, is there a way to stop opening this external program in tclsh?

Comment: In other words, how to unbind as from external program in tclsh

Comment: Read about the Tcl command `unknown`.  Then try this: `proc unknown args { }`. That may be more drastic then you want.  And to get out of 'as', type control-D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to stop opening this external program in tclsh?

Yes. From https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tclsh

> Setting `$::auto_noexec` to 1 suppresses this behaviour

You can set that in your [~/.tclshrc](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tclshrc) if you want to turn it off in every interactive tclsh session.

Comment: Not the op, but that did work here; macos 10.14.  `$ tclsh
% info patchlevel
8.6.13
% set ::auto_noexec 1
1
% date
Sat Apr  8 08:45:33 CDT 2023
%`
Which is why I suggested in a comment to override the `unknown` command.

Comment: Note also that Tcl *scripts* don't launch external programs unless you explicitly ask them to; this an interactive-only behaviour.

Comment: @aMike, where did your tclsh come from? How did you install it? On my mac, when I follow that exact sequence of commands, I get `invalid command name "date"`

Comment: Hi, Glen. macports tcl @8.6.13 on macos 10.14 (old). Just now I renamed my .tclshrc to get it out of the way, and '::auto_noexec' works as expected. I should have tested that before I commented. The '.tclshrc' sets up 'tclreadline' and adds my '~/Library/Tcl' to 'auto_path'.  So, 'tclreadline' is ignoring ::auto_noexec, I guess. Sorry for the noise.